# Column name cannot be resolved in SparkSQL join

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm not sure why this is happening. In PySpark, I read in two dataframes and print out their column names and they are as expected, but then when do a SQL join I get an error that cannot resolve column name given the inputs. I have simplified the merge just to get it to work, but I will need to add in more join conditions which is why I'm using SQL (will be adding in: "and b.mnvr_bgn < a.idx_trip_id and b.mnvr_end > a.idx_trip_data"). It appears that the column 'device_id' is being renamed to '_col7' in the df **mnvr_temp_idx_prev_temp**

```
mnvr_temp_idx_prev = mnvr_3.select('device_id', 'mnvr_bgn', 'mnvr_end')
print mnvr_temp_idx_prev.columns
['device_id', 'mnvr_bgn', 'mnvr_end']

raw_data_filtered = raw_data.select('device_id', 'trip_id', 'idx').groupby('device_id', 'trip_id').agg(F.max('idx').alias('idx_trip_end'))
print raw_data_filtered.columns
['device_id', 'trip_id', 'idx_trip_end']

raw_data_filtered.registerTempTable('raw_data_filtered_temp')
mnvr_temp_idx_prev.registerTempTable('mnvr_temp_idx_prev_temp') 
test = sqlContext.sql('SELECT a.device_id, a.idx_trip_end, b.mnvr_bgn, b.mnvr_end \
                          FROM raw_data_filtered_temp as a  \
                             INNER JOIN mnvr_temp_idx_prev_temp as b \
                                ON a.device_id = b.device_id')
```

Traceback (most recent call last): AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'b.device_id' given input columns: [_col7, trip_id, device_id, mnvr_end, mnvr_bgn, idx_trip_end]; line 1 pos 237"

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please post your complete code

Comment: My entire code is about 1000 lines so that's not really an option

Comment: Did you try using DataFrames for Join instead of sql statement? there is not much of a difference, but want to know if the same issue occurs in Dataframes as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend renaming the name of the field 'device_id' in at least one of the data frame. I modified your query just a bit and tested it(in scala). Below query works

```
test = sqlContext.sql("select * FROM raw_data_filtered_temp a INNER JOIN mnvr_temp_idx_prev_temp b ON a.device_id = b.device_id")
[device_id: string, mnvr_bgn: string, mnvr_end: string, device_id: string, trip_id: string, idx_trip_end: string]
```

Now if you are doing a 'select * ' in above statement, it will work. But if you try to select 'device_id', you will get an error "Reference 'device_id' is ambiguous" . As you can see in the above 'test' data frame definition, it has two fields with the same name(device_id). So to avoid this, I recommend changing field name in one of the dataframes.

```
mnvr_temp_idx_prev = mnvr_3.select('device_id', 'mnvr_bgn', 'mnvr_end')
                           .withColumnRenamned("device_id","device")  

raw_data_filtered = raw_data.select('device_id', 'trip_id', 'idx').groupby('device_id', 'trip_id').agg(F.max('idx').alias('idx_trip_end'))
```

Now use dataframes or sqlContext

```
//using dataframes with multiple conditions
  val test = mnvr_temp_idx_prev.join(raw_data_filtered,$"device" === $"device_id"
                                                   && $"mnvr_bgn" < $"idx_trip_id","inner")
```

//in SQL Context

```
 test = sqlContext.sql("select * FROM raw_data_filtered_temp a INNER JOIN mnvr_temp_idx_prev_temp b ON a.device_id = b.device and a. idx_trip_id < b.mnvr_bgn")
```

Above queries will work for your problem. And if your data set is too large, I would recommend to not use '>' or '<' operators in Join condition as it causes cross join which is a costly operation if data set is large. Instead use them in WHERE condition.

Comment: for your first comment, I did try using a dataframes join and got the same error.

Renaming the column in one of the dataframes fixed the issue! Now it all is running as expected. Thanks!

Thank you for the recommendation to use '>' and '<' in a where statement rather than the join...my data is really large and I wasn't aware there was a cost difference in doing this in the join vs where. So this suggestion is very appreciated!